# Why is returning None when of return type option<T> not return the null pointer when T is not a reference

Tags: c++, c, rust

[The FFI section in the nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/ffi.html#the-nullable-pointer-optimization) states that

> The most common type that takes advantage of the nullable pointer optimization is `Option<T>`, where `None` corresponds to `null`. So `Option<extern "C" fn(c_int) -> c_int>` is a correct way to represent a nullable function pointer using the C ABI (corresponding to the C type `int (*)(int)`).

However, this function does not return `null` instead returning an address.

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn test() -> Option<u8> {
    None
}
```

Rust also issues this warning :

```
warning: `extern` fn uses type `Option<u8>`, which is not FFI-safe
 --> src/lib.rs:2:29
  |
2 | pub extern "C" fn test() -> Option<u8> {
  |                             ^^^^^^^^^^ not FFI-safe
  |
  = note: `#[warn(improper_ctypes_definitions)]` on by default
  = help: consider adding a `#[repr(C)]`, `#[repr(transparent)]`, or integer `#[repr(...)]` attribute to this enum
  = note: enum has no representation hint
```

Changing the return type to `Option<Box<u8>>` makes the function return `null` as expected,

```rust
#[no_mangle]
pub extern "C" fn test2() -> Option<Box<u8>> {
    None
}
```

The functions are called from c++ using the following header file

```rust
extern "C" {
    void * test();
    void * test2();
}
```

The following c++ code

```cpp
int main()
{
    cout << test() << endl;
    cout << test2() << endl;
}
```

prints :

```
0x5555a09d1200
0
```

Comment: `nullable pointer optimization` and `u8` is not a pointer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> nullable ***pointer*** optimization.

If the `Option` contains a pointer type, such as `Box` then the optimisation can be applied. A `u8` cannot be null and is not a pointer, but a `Box<u8>` is an owned pointer to a `u8`, so the optimisation works there.

More generally, this optimisation is called "niche-filling" which also applies to a few non-pointer Rust types, notably `enums`. In the general case this is not safe for FFI though, and therefore doesn't apply to data in `#[repr(C)]` structs except for pointer types.